# Scipy: fsolve float object not iterable

Tags: python, scipy

I want to use fsolve to solve for alpha and beta (from the Beta distribution)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def mean_and_var(mu,sigma):
     a, b = mu,*sigma
     return (a/(a+b), a*b/(((a+b)**2)*(a+b+1)))


args = (.5,.05)  #mean and variance
alpha,beta  = fsolve( mean_and_var, 0, args )

#print (mean_and_var((a, b)))
```

This shoots me the error

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: What is the equation you want to solve?

Comment: there are two: mu=a/(a+b)  mu is a value we input  and for sigma=(ab)/((a+b)^2(a+b+1))  where sigma is an inputed value.  Want to solve for a and b by solving for both equations simultaneously.

Comment: fsolve solves the equations of type `f(x) = 0`, in your case who would be `f(x)`?

Comment: Okay, I just understood your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using fsolve you must modify the original equation to another one that has the form `f(x)=0`, in your case:

```
mu=a/(a+b)
sigma=(ab)/((a+b)^2(a+b+1))
```

It becomes:

```
mu - a/(a+b) = 0
sigma - a*b/(((a+b)**2)*(a+b+1)) = 0
```

n the function that we pass the first parameter is the variable that one wants to find (a, b), and the second the other parameters (mu, sigma).

```
def mean_and_var(x, *args):
    a, b = x
    mu, sigma = args 
    eq1 = mu - a/(a+b)
    eq2 = sigma - a*b/(((a+b)**2)*(a+b+1))
    return eq1, eq2

args = (.5,.05)
a, b = fsolve(mean_and_var, (.1, .1), args=args)
print("solution: {}, {}".format(a, b))
print("eval in function: {}".format(mean_and_var((a, b), *args)))
```

output:

```
solution: 1.9999999999999376, 2.000000000000059
eval in function: (1.5154544286133387e-14, -4.163336342344337e-17)
```

Comment: Maple has an fsolve option, i dont remember the solution, but i think it was an order of magnitude of 1.  My computer is currently not working, so ill check when i can

Comment: running in maple gave a=2.0000, b=2.000.  So we are good.  Thank you